# headRotation missing in GVRPanoramaView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, google-vr

I am working on a project that makes use of **Googles VR SDK**, which I like a lot.

Now I would like to play a little with the head rotation of the user, but `GVRPanoramaView` seems to be missing it member headRotation:
https://developers.google.com/vr/ios/reference/interface_g_v_r_widget_view#ab404c9aff5c57f697860ad0845d7aeb8

At least `XCode` is complaining about that. All other properties are available, which gives me the feeling that this could be a bug in the SDK.

What do you think?

I use **GVRSDK (1.10.0) BTW via CocoaPods**.